# Why doesn't my PHP script read HTML code inside a table in MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i got php script the value don't read the html code inside

i make table

```
about   text    utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

mysql

and in the templates

```
  <span class="blog-details-date">{{ __($doctor->about) }}</span>
```

when i put html code in that table

don't read the html like `<img>` or `<br>`

i guess the proplem about the table must be text or anything else ?

Comment: The templating engine is probably HTML-encoding the output. This is usually done as standard practice to guard against XSS attacks resulting from user input.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel removes html from output by default for security purposes. You can output html like this:

```
Change this: {{ __($doctor->about) }}
To This: {!! $doctor->about !!}
Or This: {!! __($doctor->about) !!}
```